# Cakephp - save data to relation model

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I've got three models: `users`, `groups` and `user_groups`

```
users table: id | alias | password ...

groups table: id | name ...

user_groups table: id | user_id (fk users table) | group_id (fk groups table) ...
```

In my groups controller, I receive data about available groups and the member:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if (!$id) throw new NotFoundException(__('Unknown Group'));
    //All available groups with members
    $group = $this->Groups->find('all', [
        'contain' => 'Users'
    ]);
    //Only the group + members with the requested id
    $member = $this->Groups->get($id, [
        'contain' => 'Users'
    ]);

    if (!$group) throw new NotFoundException(__('Group does not exist'));
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $this->Groups->patchEntity($group, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Groups->save($group)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Group successfully updated'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Failed to update group'));
    }
    $this->set('group', $group);
    $this->set('member', $member);
}
```

I'm trying to build a view containing two `selectboxes`, one for the users that are already member of the group and one for the remaining (not members) users.

When it comes to data saving to the relation model (`user_groups`) I'm totally helpless.

Do I have to use specific variable names / input field names?

How to serve the data so the controller knows where to save it?

Thanks in advance and sorry for that noob questions, I'm new to the whole framework thing.

Comment: Hi what is your cakephp version?

Comment: Hey, I'm running on 3.0.11